# Code Igniter returning blank page when uploaded to a server

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I just uploaded my codeigniter directory to my unix server and I am getting a blank page. The same directory is located in my desktop web server where it works just fine.

Also, I uploaded a fresh copy of CodeIgniter directory to my unix webserver and that just works fine.

Do any of you know what could be the problem?

Thank You.

Comment: I changed the default controller in my CodeIgniter setup to welcome to get at least the welcome message. It does not work!

Comment: Are all the paths OK? What does the log/apache (error) log say? Is the webserver properly configured? When using .htaccess, are you sure it is enabled and working?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you edited your **config.php** with proper settings located in */system/application/config/*

Answer (score 0):

Blank pages are usually caused by PHP errors. Copy and paste the code into an IDE like Aptana with live debugging and see if it throws any errors.